# Source security group isn't working as expected in AWS

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 node, node1 (security group SG1) which should be accessible from another EC2 node, node2 (security group SG2) on port 9200. Now, when I add an inbound rule in SG1 with port 9200 and specify SG2 as source in Custom IP section, I can't access node1 from node2. On the other hand, if I specify an inbound rule in SG1 with source as 0.0.0.0/0 or IP of node2, it works fine. What is wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Are you attempting to connect to node1's public or private address?  From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html):

> When you specify a security group as the source or destination for a
>   rule, the rule affects all instances associated with the security
>   group. For example, incoming traffic is allowed based on the private
>   IP addresses of the instances that are associated with the source
>   security group.

I've been burned on this before by trying to connect to an EC2 instance's public address... sounds very similar to your setup, actually.  When you wire up the inbound rule so that the source is a security group, you must communicate through the source instance's private address.

Some things to be aware of:

- In EC2 Classic, private IP addresses can change on stop/start of an EC2 instance. If you're using EC2 classic you may want to look into [this discussion on Elastic DNS Names](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=373162) for a more static addressing solution.
- If you set up your environment in VPC, [private IP addresses are static](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html). You can also change security group membership of running instances.

Comment: So, how can one whitelist a group of instances in a security group?

Comment: @LuigiLopez, if I understood it well, you create a sg with the instances that will make the requests, then you set this group as the source of the inbound rules in the second sg, where the target instance is and make sure that the requesters use the private ip addresses, instead of the public. I think that's it

Answer (score 25):

**Reason:** Inter security-group communication works over private addressing. If you use the public IP address the firewall rule will not recognise the source security group.

**Solution:** You should address your instances using the Public DNS record - this will actually be pointed at the private IP address when one of your instances queries the DNS name.

e.g. if your instance has public IP `203.0.113.185` and private IP `10.1.234.12`, you are given a public DNS name like `ec2-203-0-113-185.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`.

`ec2-203-0-113-185.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` will resolve to `203.0.113.185` if queried externally, or `10.1.234.12` if queried internally. This will enable your security groups to work as intended.

This will enable you to use an elastic IP as you simply use the Public DNS entry of the elastic IP. Also, [having the DNS resolve to the internal IP means that you are not incurring bandwidth charges for your data between instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses):

> Instances that access other instances through their public NAT IP
>   address are charged for regional or Internet data transfer, depending
>   on whether the instances are in the same region.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation and I think details the internals a lot better.
For me its definitely cleared up the confusion I was having

Answer (score -1):

The Public DNS didn't work for me. 
What I did instead was create a custom inbound rule using the security group of the other instance.