# How to allow access to ec2 instance service from another set of ec2 machines

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon web service (AWS).
I have a web server installed on one server instance (ec2).
It's served on port 8080. The machine is on a security group called "web-secgrp".

I want to allow access to that web server ONLY from another set of ec2 instances. These instances all share the same security group called "client-secgrp"

I can do this via the security groups by adding each and every individual public IP's of the set of ec2 instances to "web-secgrp". But this is not easy to maintain as I may have more or less of these machines running at once and it's just painful to add all the IP's by hand.

I noticed that in the Source of the security group, I can enter the ID of another security group. I tried entering the ID of client-secgrp in the inbound rules of web-secgroup but that seems to have no effect.
For what it's worth, I also remember that in the (very distant) past, I had to add the security group of an ec2 to the security group rules of an RDS (mysql service).

Any insight on a better way to manage the firewall ports of AWS is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24232849/775544

Comment: It is. Thank you Anthony